# Look up variable for a calculation

Tags: r

I've got a table, data', which contains sample names and measurement sizes. I need to convert size to CAG using the formula ((CAG - flank)/3)+correction. The trouble is each sample has a different 'flank' and 'correction', as defined in 'settings'. I then need to filter out rows where the CAG is less than 'start' or greater than 'end'. Start and end are defined in 'settings' and also vary for each sample.
I'd be really grateful for help adapting the calculation to index the appropriate flank and correction for each sample

```
#Example dataset
data <- data.frame(sample = c('A01', 'A01', 'A02', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04', 'A04'),
               size = c(200, 280, 315, 430, 510, 560, 610))


#Define controls for each sample
settings <- data.frame(samples = c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'),
                   flank = c(108, 108, 60, 60)
                   correction = (2, 2, 1, 1)
                   start = (10, 10, 13, 13)
                   end = (2000, 2000, 6000, 6000)
                   control = c('A01', 'A01', 'A03', 'A03')) 

#Convert size unit from bp to CAG in new column
data$CAG <- ((data$size - flank)/3)+correction

#Exclude peaks outside the window
filter <- subset(data, CAG >= start & CAG <= end)
```

Comment: Please check your input dataset.  there are some typos

Comment: Thanks akrun. The data is as it should be I think. The machine outputs measurements for the same sample on multiple rows. The number of rows differs for each sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED for OPs comments**

Make the column name for `sample` in `data` and `settings` the same. Then you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(data,settings,c=("sample")) %>% 
    mutate(CAG = ((size-flank)/3)+correction) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    filter(between(CAG,start,end)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

This will create a new column `CAG` of your output and keep only CAG values that are `>= start` and `<= end`.

```
  sample size flank correction start  end control       CAG
1    A01  200   108          2    10 2000     A01  32.66667
2    A01  280   108          2    10 2000     A01  59.33333
3    A02  315   108          2    10 2000     A01  71.00000
4    A02  430   108          2    10 2000     A01 109.33333
5    A03  510    60          1    13 6000     A03 151.00000
6    A04  560    60          1    13 6000     A03 167.66667
7    A04  610    60          1    13 6000     A03 184.33333
```

Comment: Thank you, that works nicely. Would the same idea be able to be applied to filter out the measurements smaller than start and greater than end?

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the filter step, I unfortunately get the following error:

Joining, by = "sample"
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=7]..

Answer (score 1):

You can merge both data frames so each sample will have its corresponding flank and correction. Then you do your calculations.

```
settings$sample <- settings$samples   # You need an id variable with a common name.
data_merged <- merge(data, settings, by = sample) 

data_merged$CAG <-  ((data_merged$size - data_merged$flank)/3) + data_merged$correction
```